# iOS: A Issue with Auto Layout. Simulator Result Changes As Storyboard Changes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am making my first iOS app. I encounter a problem with the auto layout and scroll view. So right now I have a scroll view on the main storyboard. The scroll view should take up the whole screen. I have other three xib files. Each one is a page in the scroll view. So I can achieve something like scrollable walkthrough thing. The issue I have right now is that. If I change the main storyboard size, the result I got from simulator will be different.

Also, when the app is loaded, it won't show the stuff I have on the screen right away. It will just show a pure black background. I need to scroll on the screen first, then all the text, image will show up. I am not sure what's wrong either. I don't have the background color for my main storyboard. May this is related to the issue above?

---

Some examples of the first problem, if I change my main storyboard to iPhone Plus size. The simulator will show the correct size for iPhone Plus device, but not for regular iPhone and iPhone X. As you can see in the image below.

[image]

If I change the storyboard to regular iPhone size. The iPhone 8 will show the right size, but plus and X will be off.

[image]

This is how I set up the constraints for my scroll view.

[image]

This is how I set up the individual xib and the scroll view in code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Set up individual view for scroll view

    let xOrigin = self.view.frame.width

    creditScreen = CreditScreenView(nibName: "CreditScreenView", bundle: nil)

    mainScroll.addSubview(creditScreen.view)

    forWeather = ForcastScreenView(nibName: "ForcastScreenView", bundle: nil)

    mainScroll.addSubview(forWeather.view)

    nowWeather  = NowScreenView(nibName: "NowScreenView", bundle: nil)

    mainScroll.addSubview(nowWeather.view)

    //mainScroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

    // set up the size for each view
    creditScreen.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

    forWeather.view.frame = CGRect(x: xOrigin, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

    nowWeather.view.frame = CGRect(x: xOrigin * 2, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

    mainScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(view.frame.width * 3), height: CGFloat(view.frame.height))
    mainScroll.contentOffset.x = view.frame.width * 3

    mainScroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: view.frame.width * 2, y: 0), animated: true)

    //Set up the location manager here.
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


}
```

I am not sure what causes the problem, maybe it's how I set up the xib? When I googled this problem, someone suggests to put a view in the main storyboard as a top-level view, then put scroll view in that top-level view. It didn't work for me. Could someone help with the problem? Thanks!

Here is the GitHub for the source code in case you need it. 
https://github.com/lucky13820/air

Comment: Please edit your question to include actual code,  or screenshots of code

Comment: @Paulw11 I replaced the screenshot with actual code. Should I add more code? I think these are the only codes that related to layout. I did all the constraints in storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing more research and a lot trial and error, I fixed it.

I added two lines of code and turn off autoresize subviews for the scrollview in attribute inspector.

```
mainScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(xOrigin * 3), height: CGFloat(self.view.frame.height))

mainScroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your black screen problem, use this code

> mainScroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: view.frame.width * 2, y: 0),
>   animated: true)

to move it to the right in the right proportion and I have tested in iPhone 8, 8 plus and X.